# Tkinter set Tk() window background color to match active ttk theme of Frame

Tags: tkinter, ttk

Is there way to know current background color used by ttk for themed frames?
In my application I allow user to change current theme to any currently installed in OS (and maybe extra themes from those beautiful available over the Internet). Obviously Windows and Linux have different set of pre-defined styles, so I cannot make any assumptions about 'correct background color'.

While all themed widgets automatically pick correct colors according to active theme, but unfortunately not the main window (the Tk() one). I tried to search for alternative "themed Tk" but didn't find any.

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Put all widgets into ttk.Frame and stretch that frame to occupy whole window. Don't like it as it forces to keep reference to the new frame and pass it to all widget creation, which makes code longer, more cumbersome. And the app has multiple daughter windows, where I'll have to do the same stuff over and over... Bottom line, ugly code with complicated maintenance, don't like it.
2. Somehow figure out background color of theme used for ttk.Frame and apply same color to `root['bg']`. I like this approach lot more as it is single place of modification, much easier to maintain. Unfortunately didn't find how to **fetch** a background color from ttk widget. Unlike classic Tk widget, they don't have 'bg' or 'background'.
3. Or maybe there is another beautiful solution that I didn't think about?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three solutions that come to mind.

You can set `themebg` to `True` when using the `ThemedTk` widget as the root window. This will cause the background of the root window to be the same as the background of a `ttk.Frame` widget.

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
root = ThemedTk(themebg=True)
```

You can use the `lookup` method of a `ttk.Style` object to get the color for a themed frame. This is what the `ThemedTk` widget uses internally to set the background color when you set `themebg` to `True`.

For example, here's a function that will switch the theme and also explicitly set the background color of the window:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
...
root = ThemedTk()
...
def switch_theme(theme):
    root.set_theme(theme)
    color = ttk.Style().lookup("TFrame", "background", default="white")
    root.configure(bg=color)
```

Finally, you could also create a themed frame and use `place` to fill the window with the frame. You can continue to put widgets in the root window without having to pass this frame to every widget creation method.

This works because the frame will have a lower stacking order than the other widgets (assuming you create it first), and because the use of `place` doesn't change the size of the parent window or other child windows.

```
background_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
background_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
```